# CSS/javascript hover error in IE8 - fine in chrome etc

Tags: javascript, css

I have a strange error with a css/javascript hover script on all ie versions.

The culprit is here: http://www.gardensandhomesdirect.co.uk

Underneath the main banner and the featured products area there are 3 'buttons', christmas, garden and home that have on-hover effects.

in firefox/chrome etc they are working fine and the hover goes over the original area as it should do. however in IE the hover moves the item over to the right?

Ive looked at the css and im not sure what isnt working from IE's point of view.

Any help on this is appreciated :)

Comment: I think you should've tagged this javascript, not java

Comment: Sorry, I thought i had. thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the style for `.hover-panel` add:

```
left: 0;
```

Comment: Nevermind, it was Netsuite not updating the css file. thank you Matt :)